# jQuery - Get content of elements, with different content, but same class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am currently creating a simple forum system for my website, and I want users to be able to quote each other.

I show each post, by doing a `while() loop` with php:

```
while ($post = $p->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

  //Post Content in here.
  <p class='post-text'>$text</p>
  <a href='javascript:void(0)' class='quote'>Quote</a>

}
```

The above code will example output:

```
<p class='post-text'>Post 1</p>
<p class='post-text'>Post 2</p>
```

When an user is to quote one of the posts, I want to get the content of the `.post-text`. How can this be achieved?

Currently, I only have this:

```
$('.quote').click(function() {

        alert($('.post-text').text());

    });
```

This will output **all** `.post-text` contents:

```
post1post2
```

Now, imagine that there is multiple posts - how can I get the content of `.post-text`, depending on which post is quoted?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An easy solution would be to include post IDs as identifiers:

```
while ($post = $p->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

  //Post Content in here.
  <p class='post-text' id='post-". $post->id ."'>$text</p>
  <a href='javascript:void(0)' class='quote' data-id='post-". $post->id ."'>Quote</a>

}
```

and then i JS:

```
$('.quote').click(function() {

    alert($('#post-'+ $(this).data('id')).text());

});
```

Comment: Can someone please explain why this answer got downwoted? It seems to be a solid solution - what's the issue? Too 'heavy'?

Comment: I think it's better then traversing the DOM because the HTML structure can change when you redesign your forum, but ids stey the same no matter what you do.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you're looking for the previous element with class .post-text, which you can get as follows:

```
$('.quote').click(function() {
    $(this).prev('.post-text').text();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Jquery .prev() selector. This selects the previous element in the DOM tree. But note that this only works if you make sure the quote button comes after the div containing the post text.

```
$('.quote').click(function() {
  alert($('.post-text').prev().text());
});
```

Comment: The quote button is not placed directly after

Answer (score 0):

### I think wrapped them inside the div tag.

```
<div class="posts">
  User A
  <p class='post-text'>Post 1A</p>
  <p class='post-text'>Post 2A</p>
  <a href='javascript:void(0)' class='quote'>Quote</a>
</div>
<div class="posts">
  User B
<p class='post-text'>Post 1B</p>
<p class='post-text'>Post 2B</p>
<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='quote'>Quote</a>
</div>
   <script>
$(".quote").click(function(){
alert($(this).parent(".posts").children(".post-text").text());
})
</script>
```

### //script: will output all posts inside the container depends on which quote was clicked